# Put limit to vertical line on chart by software control

Tags: c#, excel, charts, line, vertical-alignment

Actually my goal is just put limit line to my existing chart...
already solve the graph plot to my chart by c#. (plot is done by c#)

but now the problem is how to put limit vertical line to my chart.

```
Excel.Range chartRange;

Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)excelWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 50, 500, 250);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

excelWorksheet.Cells[4, 1] = "";
chartRange = excelWorksheet.get_Range("A4", "DSC5");   /// whatever range is ~~~
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue2);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers;
```

above code just plot graph by c#. (working successfully,,,,
problem is after plot my chart and then i just want put vertical limit line.
i couldn't do with c# but i implemented with manually in my excel.. (use my hand with mouse lol )

[image: this picture implement by manually]

above picture implement by manually.. 
simply select chart by mouse ==> design tab == > select data ==> add ==> put name ==> xval choose D4 cell, ==> Y val 0 ==> ok

layout tab ==> error bars ==> other option and change setting.

implement by manually is ok but i couldn't do this process with C#.

did anyone know that how to implement this with C#.

actually other way is ok to add vertical line to my chart.
i only want use D4 cell and E4 cell for range select.

please advice.

Comment: If I may ask, could we not accomplish this with VBA?

Comment: Yes, my solution is c#,  for now.... you means is it possible with VBA?

Comment: record a macro and look at the steps.

Comment: This is auto create process ,,, so is it possible to perform macro also by c#?

Comment: this.Application.Run("mymacro");